# ASP.NET caching helper

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm willing to simplify the use of the ASP.NET cache.

I wrote this helper class:

```
public static class CacheHelper
{
    public static T GetCached<T>(string key, Func<T> initializer, DateTime absoluteExpiration)
    {
        return GetCached(key, initializer, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, absoluteExpiration);
    }
    public static T GetCached<T>(string key, Func<T> initializer, TimeSpan slidingExpiration)
    {
        return GetCached(key, initializer, slidingExpiration, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration);
    }
    public static T GetCached<T>(string key, Func<T> initializer, TimeSpan slidingExpiration, DateTime absoluteExpiration)
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

        if (httpContext != null)
        {
            var obj = httpContext.Cache[key];
            if (obj == null)
            {
                obj = initializer();
                httpContext.Cache.Add(key, obj, null, absoluteExpiration, slidingExpiration, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
            }
            return (T)obj;
        }
        else
        {

            return initializer(); // no available cache
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to let the developer write its method as usual, but wrapping it like this:

```
public MyClass GetSomeCachedData(){
            return CacheHelper.GetCached(
                "GetSomeCachedData, () =>
                {

                        return ComputeExpensiveResult();
                }
                }, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration);
}
```

Do you see any issues?  Can it be improved?

(I'm sticking to .NET 3.5)

Comment: You could simplify your lambda to `() => ComputeExpensiveResult()`, or even just `ComputeExpensiveResult`. Also, `GetSomeCachedData()` should probably be a property.

Comment: @svick: actually the content of the lambda is most of time the body of the method, without the cache. I use this simplified syntax to focus on the helper method. That said, I don't agree with changing the method to a property. By definition a property should be inexpensive. In my case, this can be. Moreover, the typical usage of my helper method is to cache the result of a restful web service and the method is actually an operation of the service.

Answer (score 1):

Several suggestions:

1. You could use [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class as of .NET 4, which would free you from `System.Web` assembly.
2. You should use lock in order to put the value to cache.
3. You should take care of value types objects

So, here is the code:

```
public static T GetCached<T>(string key, Func<T> initializer, TimeSpan slidingExpiration, DateTime absoluteExpiration)
{
    var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

    if (httpContext != null)
    {
        key = string.Intern(key); 
        lock(key) // locking on interned key
        {
            var obj = httpContext.Cache[key];
            if (obj == null)
            {
                obj = initializer();
                httpContext.Cache.Add(key, obj, null, absoluteExpiration, slidingExpiration, System.Web.Caching.CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
            }
            // taking care of value types
            if (obj == null && (typeof (T)).IsValueType)
            {
                return default(T);
            }
            return (T)obj;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return initializer(); // no available cache
    }
}
```

Comment: as I said, I'm sticked to the version 3.5 of the framework. That said, I think your lock is useless as the key is a string, and make the lock useless as the instance of the string will always be different, isn't it?

Comment: Every time the method would called with same key value, `string.Intern(key)` would return reference to same string, so lock should work as needed.